# How to bind html from JSON API in Angular 8

Tags: html, json, angular7, angular8

i am trying to display data from API in Angular 8 But this API include a html code 
and when i try to show it in the page the html show up without working 
Like this [image][image]

i am wondering how can i compile the html to look like it supposed to be

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is answered here:
[Angular HTML binding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31548311/angular-html-binding)

You can use *either* this:
`<div [innerHTML]="current_page.data.details"></div>`

*or* `<div innerHTML="{{current_page.data.details}}"></div>`

Check the reference: https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#property-binding-vs-interpolation

Comment: Not working and i don't think it's gonna work inside loop

Comment: sure it will work, it does matter if its a loop or not, you should use **ngFor** for iteration.  Also you can parse the html pragmatically from your component.Please update your question and show your code (component + html template).

Comment: this one is working <div innerHTML="{{course.details}}"></div>